# PHP - Accessing a object property from dynamic variable

Tags: php, oop

I'm looking for accessing a property of a object property of an object like this :

```
$property = "user->name";
echo $object->$property; // ??, I want $object->user->name
```

I tried a lot of things, but none seems work.

Thanks

Comment: What ?? Can you explain briefly .. show your object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access nested object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037240/dynamically-access-nested-object)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, I can't use XPath as suggested because this is not XML, and I cannot access directly to what I want. To answer to M A SIDDIQUI, I need to store the property of an object as shown ($property) and reuse this variable on the $object object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can make multiple dereferences this way. You'll be looking for a variable in `$object` called `user->name`. Instead, you can split by `->` and then make multiple calls, something like:

```
$test = 'user->name';
$val = $object;
foreach(explode('->', $test) as $item) {
  $val = $val->$item;
}
echo $val;   # This is the result of $object->user->name
```

[Sample Code](https://repl.it/FlhQ)

Comment: Shouldn't the first "$var" be a "$val"? . 

Apart from this, this raw statement works in my code: echo $json_dump->geometry[6]->obs[2]->hayabusa2->delay_from; But I cannot "simulate" it by assigning "geometry[6]->obs[2]->hayabusa2->delay_from" to $test and using your code, I get error "Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$geometry[6] "

Answer (score 1):

If you split your variable into 2 like so:

```
    list($property1, $property2) = explode('->', $property);

    echo $object->{$property1}->{$property2};
```

Comment: Less flexible, but more performant and highly legible. +1 for avoiding recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
$property = "user->name";

$prop_arr = explode('->',$property);
foreach ($prop_arr as $prop){
    $obj = $obj->{$prop};
}
echo $obj;
```